# How to generate random number of lognormal distribution using scipy.stats lognorm with mean and standard deviation already known

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scipy.stats

I want to generate a random number of lognormal distribution using the scipy.stats lognorm. I have mean and standard deviation already give.

```
from scipy.stats import lognorm

sigma = 5
mean = 0
randomNumber = lognorm.rvs(sigma, mean)
print(randomNumber)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After reading the scipy.stats.lognorm page: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html

The lognorm.rvs() accepts one mandatory argument 's' (shape). The 's' is determined by the Sigma and by default the scale is 1. You can adjust it according to your condiotns like:

```
randomNumber = lognorm.rvs(s =sigma,scale= exp(mean))
print(randomNumber)
```

Thanks